# Setting Up Verisign SSL For Local Server

Tags: ssl

I'm working on a local database and want all connections to this server to use SSL. I've read that self-signing SSL certificates are not very secure and using a trusted Certificate Authority, like Verisign, is best. Is it possible to setup a Verisign SSL on a local server?

The database, on occasions, will aslo send data out to an external database and I want this information to be encrypted as well. Will I need to certificates or can I use the same one?

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed SSL certificates are just as secure, they're just not endorsed by a Certificate Authority.

If you run a public website, you would want your visitors to know that they're connected to you, by having the certificate signed by Verisign (or another trusted CA), their browser can confirm and acknowledge that they are actually connected to you.

When connecting via a self signed certificate, the browser will display a warning since it does not recognize the CA (You are the CA for a self signed cert). You can add yourself to your browser's "trusted CAs" and it won't display the error anymore for you, but if someone else visits your site with their own browser, it will display the warning again.

Here's a good primer on HTTP/SSL/CAs:
http://wpengine.com/support/how-does-all-this-work-https-ssl-certificates-ca-public-and-private-keys-csrs/